# How to fix jQuery syntax error while passing value to an element with quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have trouble passing values to an element using `.text()` or `.html()`
when the data/values start and end with `"` or `'`, like examples below:

- Using single quote: `$(".elem").html(''');` or `$(".elem").html(''data_here'');`
- Using double quote: `$(".elem").html(""");` or `$(".elem").html(""data_here"");`

I tried to pass the value to a variable as below, but still the same.

- Passing to a variable first:

  ```
  var data = data_with_single_or_doble_qoute;
  $(".elem").html(data); or $(".elem").html(data);
  ```

I'm doing a rails project using .js.erb file. My actual code is:

```
$(".elem").html("<%= raw(@message.body[0..100]) %>");
```

Tried like:

```
var data = "<%= raw(@message.body[0..100]) %>";
$(".elem").html(data);
```

Hi.

How can I use to_json, since I'm not using ajax request to get the data from rails controller. Btw I'm doing a Rails Chat with private_pub. So it renders the data in real time without using js to pickup data once form was submitted. 
Code was like:

```
1. controller= @path = conversation_path(@conversation) 
2. js.erb = <% publish_to @path do %> .... <%= raw(@message.body[0..100]) %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try escaping using `escape_javascript` [`ActionView::Helpers::JavaScriptHelper::Encoding`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html) as follows:

```
$(".elem").html("<%= raw j(@message.body[0..100]) %>");
```

But, the [`raw`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/RawOutputHelper/raw) is not necessary here.  Please see the linked documentation.

Try using the following instead of your actual code:

```
$(".elem").html("<%= j @message.body[0..100] %>");
```

Comment: Hi @vee

Thank you very much for the help. I successfully render either single or double qoute. But I also used "raw" because without it (will display HTML entity like ' = &apos;)

Comment: Final code is $('.elem').html("<%= j raw(@message.body[0..100]) %>");  Thanks @vee

Answer (score -1):

```
var data = <%=raw @message.body[0..100].to_json %>;
```

Use JSON - it can be evaluated as JS data types. `#to_json` will provide quotes in correct places, including the proper escaping, if the value is a string.

Comment: So what would make a difference between `to_json` adding quotes vs the dev adding quotes surrounding erb tags?

Comment: @vee: The contents being escaped or not (and also handling other data types). if `foo = "\"foo\""`, `"var foo = <%= foo %>"` is `var foo = ""foo""`, a syntax error; but  `var foo = <%= foo.to_json %>"` is `var foo = "\"foo\""`, which is proper JavaScript.

Comment: Does your method provide "escaped" or "non escaped" value? or am I confused? http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/RawOutputHelper/raw

Comment: @vee: `raw` provides strings without HTML escaping; you would use it to render pre-rendered HTML (e.g. `"<div>foo</div>"`, not JS strings. `#to_json` provides JavaScript escaping and quoting as appropriate for each supported datatype - it is the perfect way to deliver JavaScript values. However, you might be right that I need `raw` here as well, since Rails now does HTML escaping by default. I will edit it in.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried prepending `\` on qoutation marks like this:

```
var data = " \"<%= raw(@message.body[0..100]) %>\" ";
$(".elem").html(data);
```

Comment: Could you please show how this would change the result?  Could you please perhaps show the result.